# How to avoid rowcolour being applied to \caption in longtabu environment

Tags: tables, color

I have used the following code to create table using tabu package, I have applied alternate row colours to the table using `\rowcolors` command. The issue is the colour fill is applied to the caption of the table. How can I avoid it. I tried using `\rowcolor{white}` inside the table but it throws an error.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\tabulinesep = 3mm
\rowcolors{2}{white}{lightgray}
\begin{longtabu}{>{\bf}X[l]X[l]X[r]X[r]}
\toprule
\textbf{AssetName} & \textbf{wk\_yr} & \textbf{Energy$kWh$} & \textbf{Power$kW$} 
\\ \toprule \endhead
  UPS Room & 2014-W25 & 325.45 & 1 \\ 
  UPS Room & 2014-W26 & 348.64 & 2 \\ 
  GF AHU Energy Meter & 2014-W25 & 109.00 & 13.91 \\ 
  GF AHU Energy Meter & 2014-W26 & 171.00 & 27.64 \\ 
  PANTRY AHU Energy Meter & 2014-W25 & 18.00 & 13.49 \\ 
  PANTRY AHU Energy Meter & 2014-W26 & 21.00 & 13.79 \\ 
  1F AHU Energy Meter & 2014-W25 & 19.00 & 9.01 \\ 
  1F AHU Energy Meter & 2014-W26 & 16.00 & 8.97 \\ 
\toprule
\caption{Table Caption}
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the latex code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not an elegant way, I finally got a solution to avoid the fill in table caption by using `caption` package and `\addtablecounter` command. I removed the `\caption` command inside the `longtabu` environment and used `\addtablecounter` to subtract the table count and used `\captionof` command to create caption outside the `longtabu` environment. 
Can somebody suggest better way of doing this.

```
usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\tabulinesep = 3mm
\rowcolors{2}{white}{lightgray}
\begin{longtabu}{>{\bf}X[l]X[l]X[r]X[r]}
\toprule
\textbf{AssetName} & \textbf{wk\_yr} & \textbf{Energy$kWh$} & \textbf{Power$kW$} 
\\ \toprule \endhead
  UPS Room & 2014-W25 & 325.45 & 1 \\ 
  UPS Room & 2014-W26 & 348.64 & 2 \\ 
  GF AHU Energy Meter & 2014-W25 & 109.00 & 13.91 \\ 
  GF AHU Energy Meter & 2014-W26 & 171.00 & 27.64 \\ 
  PANTRY AHU Energy Meter & 2014-W25 & 18.00 & 13.49 \\ 
  PANTRY AHU Energy Meter & 2014-W26 & 21.00 & 13.79 \\ 
  1F AHU Energy Meter & 2014-W25 & 19.00 & 9.01 \\ 
  1F AHU Energy Meter & 2014-W26 & 16.00 & 8.97 \\ 
\toprule
\end{longtabu}
\addtocounter{table}{-1}
\captionof{table}{Table Caption}
\end{document}
```

[image: Modified Table]